# How to make the mongoose update array work properly?

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

this is my schema.it has a user field and an array of object which contains a text message and direction will hold a either sent or received value.

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  
    
        user:{type: String,required: true},
        textArray:[
            {
                text:{type: String,required: true},
               
                direction:{ type: String,required: true }
                
            }]
    

});
```

This is the router code.btw should there be double quotes on the keys in var textmessage?

```
router.post('/',async(req,res)=>{
    const {user,text,direction}=req.body;
    
    const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
    
   

     
        var textmessage={
            "text":text,
            "direction":direction
        }
        const doc = await Message.updateOne(
            { user: user },
            { $set: { user:user,$push:{textArray:textmessage}} },
            { upsert: true },
            function(err,result){
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else{
                    console.log(result)
                    res.send(result)
                }// Make this update into an upsert
            });

      })
```

this is how it showsup in mongodb.the user is working ok but when i click theres is  nothing under textArray.What am I doing wrong exactly?

[image: mongo error]

Answer (score 0):

you are using await with callback function , which is wrong :

```
const filter = { user: user };
const update = { $push:{textArray:textmessage}};

let doc = await Message.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
  new: true,
  upsert: true 
});

console.log('doc=',doc);
```

Comment: sadly it didnt help .before changing the user field was showing changes and the array was not. now no change whatsoever is showing up in mongo.

Comment: @DebadityaSinha , try updated answer